# D7 Views: content associated with a user via tags

Tags: 7, views

I want to display a View of all content relevant to the logged in user based on tags that are defined in a node referenced by the user. Something that follows this relationship:

Logged in User --(references)--> Customer Subscription -(shares tags with)-> Content

The view should show all the Content associated with the user based on this logic.
I prefer to do this via modules and not code.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe these links could be a good starting point, as they provide a step by step guide of how to configure views with a relationship to the current user:

http://blog.hsl.virginia.edu/drupalpress/show-users-any-content-that-matches-any-taxonomy-term-in-views/

http://blog.ampli.fi/filtering-a-drupal-7-view-based-on-a-user-profile-field/

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers.  Normally, answers that just contain links aren't considered good ones here.  Can you summarize the posts?

Comment: sorry, I just added a brief description of both links.